# I am getting Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy error and some times 500 internal server error after making an http post request

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, http-post

I'm getting these error after sending a post request

I'm trying to send an array of the id's of the checkbox that have been checked recently here is my code:

this array is being filled after an http get request

```
  user_groups: Array <any> = [];
```

this is the function that build the selected values and send them

```
addUserGroups(user_id) {
    this.spinner.show();
    const new_groups = this.getSelectedGroups();
    // this.userugroups = new_groups;
    const formdata = {
      'Groups_id': new_groups,
      'User_Id': user_id,
    };
    console.log('fromdata: ', formdata);
    this.authent.assignroles(formdata).then((res) => {
      this.spinner.hide();
      console.log('res: ', res);
      this.ngOnInit();
      this.alerts.push({
        id: 1,
        type: 'success',
        message: 'user have benn added to groups'
      });
    }, (err) => {
      this.spinner.hide();
      this.ngOnInit();
      this.alerts.push({
        id: 1,
        type: 'warning',
        message: err.json().Message
      });
      console.log('error: ', err);
    });
  }
```

this is the function i'm using to get the new selected checkboxes

```
  getSelectedGroups() {
    return this.user_groups
              .filter(group => group.selected)
              .map(group => group.role_id);
  }
```

i tried to fix it at my university i got error 500 internal server error but when i'm at home i get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api-accountingsystem.azurewebsites.net/api/groups/user/roles' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

if someone can please help me to fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)